# AbstractServletInputStream missing on tomcat-embed-core 8.5.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8

Recently updated a java project from spring-boot 1.3.0 to 1.4.0, which is using a tomcat-embed-core 8.0.28 now AbstractServletInputStream is missing on the latest version of spring boot which is using tomcat-embed-core 8.5.4. What is the alternative/replacement of this class?

Here's the old code block, I hope it helps my case:

```
public class MultiReadHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    ...
    public class CachedServletInputStream extends AbstractServletInputStream {
        private ByteArrayInputStream input;

        public CachedServletInputStream() {
            input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cachedBytes.toByteArray());
        }

        /**
        * Returns true. This stream is always ready.
        */
        @Override
        protected boolean doIsReady() throws IOException {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Reads the next set of bytes into the byte array.
         */
        @Override
        protected int doRead(boolean b, byte[] bytes, int i, int i1) throws IOException {
            return input.read(bytes, i, i1);
        }

       /**
        * Closes this stream. This does not affect any other streams that are dependent
        * on the cached content.
        */
        @Override
        protected void doClose() throws IOException {
            input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using it? No reason surely why you can't just use `ServletInputStream` or even `InputStream`.

Comment: The project was scheduled for an upgrade and I was assign to do the task. If ServletInputStream is sufficient then that's good to know.

Comment: @Leo Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CoyoteInputStream`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteInputStream.html) instead of [`AbstractServletInputStream`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/coyote/http11/upgrade/AbstractServletInputStream.html)

Answer (score 1):

I did this, Seems to work.

```
public class CachedServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {
    private ByteArrayInputStream input;
    private boolean finished;

    public CachedServletInputStream() {
        input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cachedBytes.toByteArray());
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int b = input.read();
        finished = b == -1;
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFinished() {
        return finished;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReady() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {
    }
}
```